# Hyperledger Sawtooth nodes do not connect

Tags: hyperledger-sawtooth

I am setting up a Hyperledger Sawtooth network with four nodes on Ubuntu 16.04. I am using static peering. Here is an example validator.toml file:

```
bind = [
  "network:tcp://0.0.0.0:8800",
  "component:tcp://127.0.0.1:4004",
  "consensus:tcp://127.0.0.1:5050"
]
peering = "static"
endpoint = "tcp://<IP 1>:8800"
peers = ["tcp://<IP 2>:8800", "tcp://<IP 3>:8800", "tcp://<IP 4>:8800"]
scheduler = 'serial'
network_public_key = 'wFMwoOt>yFqI/ek.G[tfMMILHWw#vXB[Sv}>l>i)'
network_private_key = 'r&oJ5aQDj4+V]p2:Lz70Eu0x#m%IwzBdP(}&hWM*'
minimum_peer_connectivity = 3
maximum_peer_connectivity = 10
```

On server 2, I have `<IP 2>` as endpoint and `<IP 1>`, `<IP 3>` and `<IP 4>` as peers, etc.

After starting my network, I tested it using the intkey transaction family. Key/value pairs I added with `intkey set <someKey> <someValue>` were not reproduced when I did `intkey show <someValue>`. In the validator logs I saw many `Can't send message PING_RESPONSE back to...` and `No response from...` messages. Using `curl localhost:8008/peers` I observed that the peers lists had many repetitions.

Answer (score 0):

In your `validator.toml` files, let your `peers` entries point only in one direction. In the example `validator.toml` of server 2, omit `<IP 1>` from the peers list. On server 3, omit `<IP 1>` and `<IP 2>`. On server 4 you do not configure peers because it is peered from the other servers.

Comment: Yes.
Also, what consensus mechanism are you using? I think with RAFT, it is best to turn up the validators in order backward direction with static peering, for dev. Val1 - No peers, Val2 - Val1 as peer, Val3 - Val1, Val2 as peers, Val4 - all other validators.

Answer (score 0):

That does not seem right. With static peering you list all the other peers in the network for all nodes. Here's an example with Kubernetes (note the `--peers` command line flags for each validator. Maybe there's a bug or other configuration problem.

Edit: I am told that setup above avoids extra connection attempts and warning messages.

Comment: Hello Dan. You refer to an example but I do not see it in your text. Maybe it is because I am reading from my phone. Can you edit your answer to include your example?